# Check if HTML content has current website url using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE as my HTML editor. I want to perform mobile and URL validation.

**Should not be allowed**:
When user types any mobile number or any URL apart from the current website URL system should throw a validation error.

I have used below code to validate mobile and url but the moment I upload image via TinyMCE editor, the content consists of image tag with image URL this is where my code is failing.

```js
    function hasURL(str) {
      var res = str.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);

      return (res !== null);
    }

 $('#btnClick').click(function() {

    const PATTERN_MOBILE_INDIA = /\b([0|+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})\b/;
    var myText = '<p><img src="https://example.com/images/image_1568090359_myimg.jpg" alt="" width="564" height="290" /></p><p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don t look even slightly believable.</p><p>9524026761</p><p>Website: https://google.com/</p><p>If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>';
    var match = myText.match(PATTERN_MOBILE_INDIA);
    var contains = match != null;
    var hasUrl = hasURL(myText);
    var currentDomainUrl = ['https://example.com/', 'http://example.com/',
    'example.com'];

    if (contains || hasUrl) {
      // Check If "myText" have any image url or any url in content as the 
       // same url of current website url then no error will be thrown.
       // validation error
       alert('mobile number and url in content not allowed!');
       return false;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="btnClick">Check Validation</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include a [mre] of the issue. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have updated with my code sample.